# Vagrant environment very slow

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

I am running a vagrant environment and it is running very slowly. My console shows the following:

```
Completed 200 OK in 554.7ms (Views: 525.7ms | ActiveRecord: 8.5ms)
```

however it takes my browser another ten seconds to actually load the page. I had synced_folders but have stripped them out to try to improve performance but to no avail.

My vagrantfile is as follows:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5432, host: 5432
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # config.vm.synced_folder "../Base", "/Base", type: "nfs"
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../v2-api", "/API", type: "nfs"
end
```

My settings for the VM in virtual box are as follows:

```
Version: Ubuntu (64 Bit)
System > Motherboard: 4096MB
System > Processor: 2CPU
Display > Screen: 8MB
```

My computer has the following:

```
i7-6500U @ 2.5GHz
12GB RAM
64 Bit
```

Answer (score 1):

I realised it was a conflict in the hosts file. I believe this conflict was causing the slow response time. Removed the conflict and running a lot faster.